# How to Register Styles, Scripts & Blocks for WordPress Gutenberg Block Editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have created some custom blocks for the editor, the blocks are working but I am having an issue with the CSS.

`blocks.editor.build.css` loads in the editor and the frontend, it should only load in the editor.

`blocks.style.build.css` should load in both spots but doesn't load anywhere.

Also, is there a better way to register the blocks so I don't have to repeat the `register_block_type()` code for each new block I make?

```
function my_register_custom_blocks() {
    // Editor JS
    wp_register_script(
        'my-custom-blocks',
        plugins_url('/blocks/dist/blocks.build.js', __FILE__),
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-components')
    );

    // Frontend & Editor Styles  
    wp_register_style(
        'my-custom-blocks-style',
        plugins_url( '/blocks/dist/blocks.style.build.css', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks' )
    );

    // Editor Only Styles
    wp_register_style(
        'my-custom-blocks-edit-style',
        plugins_url('/blocks/dist/blocks.editor.build.css', __FILE__),
        array( 'wp-edit-blocks' )
    );  

    // Divder Block
    register_block_type('custom-blocks/divider', array(
        'editor_script' => 'my-custom-blocks',
        'editor_style' => 'my-custom-blocks-edit-style',
        'style' => 'my-custom-blocks-style'
    ));

    // Spacer Block
    register_block_type('custom-blocks/block-spacer', array(
        'editor_script' => 'my-custom-blocks',
        'editor_style' => 'my-custom-blocks-edit-style',
        'style' => 'my-custom-blocks-style'
    ));

    ...More Blocks
}

add_action('init', 'my_register_custom_blocks');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the structure of [create-guten-block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block), that way you need to use these scripts/styles once

```
├── .gitignore
├── plugin.php //add plugin info and add init.php file
├── package.json
├── README.md
|
├── dist
|  ├── blocks.build.js
|  ├── blocks.editor.build.css
|  └── blocks.style.build.css
|
└── src
   ├── block
   |  ├── block.js
   |  ├── editor.scss
   |  └── style.scss
   |
   ├── blocks.js // import each new block here to show up on editor
   ├── common.scss
   └── init.php // register scripts & styles here
```